# Select unique next event

Tags: mysql

I have a table tv_programs (prog_id, channel_id, prog_name, prog_start_date, prog_end_date)

I would like to have, for each channel, the very next program that will start after the one being broadcast now. So one row per channel.

I tried

```
Select * from tv_programs where prog_start_date > NOW()
```

This gives me all programs for all channels starting after now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to `GROUP BY channel_id`

so the final query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tv_programs 
WHERE prog_start_date > NOW() 
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY prog_start_date ASC
```

will return the program to start the sooner for each channel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tv_programs 
WHERE prog_start_date > NOW() 
GROUP BY channel_id            # for each channel
ORDER BY prog_start_date ASC   # order by this channel's start time
```

Any good?

Comment: this will only give one item and not one item per channel

Comment: I saved my answer before I finished sorry.. any better?

Comment: if you limit to one, will it return one row, or one row per channel?

Comment: I've taken the LIMIT off.. my answer would have limited to one record.. not one record per channel.. not sure how you would do this unless you do it in the server code.